# My ADT dlist has an unnecessary parameter but it clearifys the code - should I keep it?

Tags: c, parameters, linked-list, arguments

My ADT dlist has a function that inserts some data into the dlist and takes three arguments: the dlist, the data and after which dlist element to insert the data after. The dlist parameter is however redundant in this situation, but I must say it makes it clearer to me since I see which dlist I am inserting in. Would it make sense to keep it despite being redundant?

```
typedef struct dlist_element{
    void* p_data;
    struct dlist_element* p_next;
}dlist_element;

typedef struct dlist{
    struct dlist_element* p_head;
    freeFunction p_freeDataFunction;
}dlist;
```

Full .c source file

```
dlist* dlist_create(void){
    dlist* p_dlist = calloc(1, sizeof(dlist));
    p_dlist->p_head = calloc(1, sizeof(dlist_element));
    p_dlist->p_freeDataFunction = NULL;
    return p_dlist;
}

void dlist_setDataFreeFunction(dlist* p_dlist, freeFunction p_freeDataFunction){
    p_dlist->p_freeDataFunction = p_freeDataFunction;
}

void dlist_insert(dlist* p_dlist, void* p_data, dlist_element* p_preceding){
    dlist_element* p_new = malloc(sizeof(dlist_element));
    p_new->p_data = p_data;
    p_new->p_next = p_preceding->p_next;
    p_preceding->p_next = p_new;
}

void* dlist_inspect(dlist_element* p_element){
    return p_element->p_next->p_data;
}

void* dlist_remove(dlist_element* p_element){
    void* p_data = p_element->p_next->p_data;
    dlist_element* p_remove = p_element->p_next;
    p_element->p_next = p_remove->p_next;
    free(p_remove);
    return p_data;
}

bool dlist_isEmpty(dlist* p_dlist){
    return p_dlist->p_head->p_next == NULL;
}

dlist_element* dlist_first(dlist* p_dlist){
    return p_dlist->p_head;
}

dlist_element* dlist_next(dlist_element* p_element){
    return p_element->p_next;
}

bool dlist_isEnd(dlist_element* p_element){
    return p_element->p_next == NULL;
}

void dlist_free(dlist* p_dlist){
    dlist_element* p_remove = p_dlist->p_head->p_next;
    dlist_element* p_removeNext = NULL;
    while (p_remove != NULL){
        p_removeNext = p_remove->p_next;
        if (p_dlist->p_freeDataFunction != NULL){
            p_dlist->p_freeDataFunction(p_remove->p_data);
        }
        free(p_remove);
        p_remove = p_removeNext;
    }
    free(p_dlist->p_head);
    free(p_dlist);
}
```

Comment: If it is redundant, how would the function know which list to insert it into?

Comment: It really doesn't make any sense that the list argument itself would be redundant. *Why* is it redundant? How else would the function know which list the value should be inserted into?

Comment: The only thing needed is the data and list element since I am inserting it directly after the given element.

Comment: Say you want to insert it first in the list, you pass dlist_first(p_dlist) as the "after element" argument.

Comment: So you have an ADT for the actual list (the A in ADT stands for *abstract*, which kind of implies opaque), but still lets users of the list have access to the internal node structures?

Comment: Well, it sounds like your implementation could be improved. An ADT user should not be provided with access to the list *elements* as they are, but to some abstraction of them (like index, for example.).

Comment: I am probably as confused as you are now, I will try putting the source code here in a minute.

Comment: Couldn't post code in comments so I edited my question. Anyway, I posted the code I thought was of interest for you.

Comment: The point is that `p_preceding` pointer should have never been given to the user.

Comment: If you want to insert the data after the 'preceding' node, then there's no point in passing the list too — it just opens up the possibility of confusion because the list passed doesn't contain the (pointer to) node that it is passed.  If you want to insert at the start or end of the list, then it makes sense not to pass the preceding node.  Don't pass both.

Comment: If I removed the A in ADT would it have been okay then?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, and when I look at it now I believe it has two sides to it. When iterating through the list it might be confusing to also add the list since you only care about which element,  but when writing like dlist_insert(p_dlist, data, dlist_first(p_dlist)) at least in my opinion it was clearer.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.  A lot depends on your expected usage patterns.  The `dlist_insert(p_dlist, data, dlist_first(p_dlist))` notation feels funny; I've often wanted to add nodes at the start of a list, or at the end of the list, but seldom wanted to add them at the second point in the list.  Review how you think the code will be used; decide what to do; be prepared to change your mind after using the code for a bit (or when you use it on the next project).  My preference would be 'one of the two' and 'not both'.  But you'd need a separate `dlist_insert_head()`, etc.

Comment: Having a dlist_last would actually be really good instead of having to iterate through the whole thing. And for the record, dlist_insert(data, dlist_first(p_dlist)) would actually put it at the first place at the list, not second. I know it is confusing hehe... I will post the full source code just to make it clearer.

Comment: Confusing APIs are generally bad.  I'm not sure how your code would get the new node to the front of the list; if you do that, you have to update the `p_head` element of the list or you're in serious trouble — you've got an allocated node that you can't access from the start of the list.  You need to review your design — carefully.

Comment: The head element isn't a element that the user can access. Its only use is to get the list to work internally.

When calling dlist_first it will retrieve the head element, which to the user is literally garbage, but that doesn't matter since the user shouldn't attempt to use the dlist_element directly, but instead should use the functions for the dlist.

When the user inspects a value he/she will use the dlist_element that was returned by dlist_first. It will return the next element after that.

Lets say we iterate the list with help of dlist_next. Now we find an element (TBC)

Comment: in the middle of the list that we want to remove. Since we actually are on the previous element interally we can remove it immediately without having to iterate through the whole list to that element again. So we saved a lot of time.